# Oracle error: ORA-06550: line 12, column 4

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

## Oracle gives me the following error when performing a redefinition of a table.

This code worked fine for other redefinitions in other tables.

```
SQL> BEGIN
      2  
      3  -- **************************************************************
      4  -- Start the Redefinition Process
      5  -- **************************************************************
      6  BEGIN
      7  DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table(
      8  uname      => 'User',
      9  orig_table => 'SAN_RELAC_PERSONA',
     10  int_table      => 'NEW_SAN_RELAC_PERSONA',
     11  options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
     12  END;
     13  /
END;
   *
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
<a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge
```

Comment: why do you have BEGIN twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `BEGIN BEGIN` but not `END; END;`

You can either add a second `END` as others are suggesting, or else lose a `BEGIN`.

```
begin
    dbms_redefinition.start_redef_table
    ( uname        => 'User'
    , orig_table   => 'SAN_RELAC_PERSONA'
    , int_table    => 'NEW_SAN_RELAC_PERSONA'
    , options_flag => dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid );
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove line 13 `/`:

```
BEGIN

   -- **************************************************************
   -- Start the Redefinition Process
   -- **************************************************************
   BEGIN
   DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table(
   uname      => 'User',
   orig_table => 'SAN_RELAC_PERSONA',
   int_table      => 'NEW_SAN_RELAC_PERSONA',
   options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
   END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slash (`/`) symbol is in the wrong place - it should end the script, so you should put it after the last `END` keyword. I hope it helps.

```
BEGIN
        -- **************************************************************
        -- Start the Redefinition Process
        -- **************************************************************
       BEGIN
       DBMS_REDEFINITION.start_redef_table(
       uname      => 'User',
       orig_table => 'SAN_RELAC_PERSONA',
       int_table      => 'NEW_SAN_RELAC_PERSONA',
       options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
       END;
END;
/
```

Comment: I think the OP entered the command interactively, and the final `END;` is part of the error message, i.e. the compiler is reporting an error at line 12.